# Oracle COUNT() function

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have this query:

```
    select dates,To_char(dates,'DAY') DAYs FROM
    (
     select trunc(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1),'MM') +  level -1 Dates from dual connect by
      level <= ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),1)-1 -  trunc(sysdate,'MM')+1
   ) Where To_char(dates,'DY') NOT IN ('SA','SO')
```

The output of query above is:

```
01.05.2015  FREITAG   
04.05.2015  MONTAG    
05.05.2015  DIENSTAG  
06.05.2015  MITTWOCH  
07.05.2015  DONNERSTAG
08.05.2015  FREITAG   
11.05.2015  MONTAG    
12.05.2015  DIENSTAG  
13.05.2015  MITTWOCH  
14.05.2015  DONNERSTAG
15.05.2015  FREITAG   
18.05.2015  MONTAG    
19.05.2015  DIENSTAG  
20.05.2015  MITTWOCH  
21.05.2015  DONNERSTAG
22.05.2015  FREITAG   
25.05.2015  MONTAG    
26.05.2015  DIENSTAG  
27.05.2015  MITTWOCH  
28.05.2015  DONNERSTAG
29.05.2015  FREITAG
```

I was not expecting this output. Instead, I wanted to count all these days (21), which should be my only output.

The final Result should be:

```
DAYS
--
21
```

Comment: Clearly, you know about the `COUNT()` function, because you have it in the title.  So why didn't you try to use it?  How were you not expecting the output that you got, if you don't have a `COUNT()` in the original query?   (homework assignment?)

Comment: You run a statement that starts with `select dates,To_char(dates,'DAY') DAYs FROM...` and you are surprised that it doesn't return a single value? Why would you expect a query that selects **two** columns without aggregates to return a **single**, aggregated column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) DAYs FROM
    (
     select trunc(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate,-1),'MM') +  level -1 Dates from dual connect by
      level <= ADD_MONTHS(trunc(sysdate,'MM'),1)-1 -  trunc(sysdate,'MM')+1
   ) Where To_char(dates,'DY') NOT IN ('SA','SO')
```